# Django - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm trying to deploy a Django app that works locally, but doesn't on my website. The Django index.html (template) is shown but the errors below are shown and no css / js is loaded.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) - http://example.com/static/js/main
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) - http://example.com/static/css/style.css
```

Lines I think are relevant in settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'src.pages'
]
```

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'pages/static'),
]
```

How I include the files in index.html template

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="{% static 'js/main.js' %}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

App structure is as follows

```
web_app/
├── src/
│   ├── config/
│   │   └── settings.py
│   ├── pages/
│   │   ├── static/
│   │   │   ├── css/
│   │   │   │   └── style.css
│   │   │   ├── js/
│   │   │   │   └── main.js
│   │   │   └── fonts/
│   │   ├── templates/
│   │   │   └── pages/
│   │   │       └── index.html
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   └── static (generated with collectstatic)/
│       ├── admin
│       ├── css/
│       │   └── style.css
│       ├── js/
│       │   └── main.js
│       └── fonts
├── manage.py
└── requirements.txt
```

Tried moving the JS code into index.html and it worked, so I'm guessing it can't find the static files for some reason.

I also tried setting the absolute path to the css file but it gives the same error.

Comment: Hi @J3punen! Are you declaring the static urls in urls.py? Add your code in that case, otherwise, that's maybe what you are missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django won't serve static files, only the dev server (runserver) is configured to do so, you either let the static files to be serve from the HTTP server that in front of Django (e.g Apache2 or Nginx) which is recommended method,  or use [whitenouse](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/latest/)